# How can I fix a Range.Value assignment issue in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have some VBA code to re-calculate subtotals on a worksheet change event.  The subtotals are then assigned to the appropriate cells.  The code below works, but the cell values aren't getting updated.  When I put it in debugger and step through the code, FreightTotal and OtherTotal are calculated correctly and rw references the correct row.  The value in the two variables isn't getting assigned to the cells.  I have no idea what is going on, it should work.

```
    Sheet1.Range("H" & rw).Value = FreightTotal
    Sheet1.Range("J" & rw).Value = OtherTotal
```

Here is the if full loop:

```
If Target.Column = 8 Then
    For rw = 11 To 36
        If Range("A" & rw).Value = "Total" Then
            i = rw - 1
            FreightTotal = 0
            OtherTotal = 0
            Do While Range("BA" & i).Value = Range("BA" & rw).Value
                FreightTotal = FreightTotal + Range("H" & i).Value
                OtherTotal = OtherTotal + Range("J" & i).Value
                i = i - 1
            Loop
            Sheet1.Range("H" & rw).Value = FreightTotal
            Sheet1.Range("J" & rw).Value = OtherTotal
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: My first guess is that this is a Worksheet_Change event.  Is the code where this event is located in the `Sheet1` code module?  I'm guessing that it isn't, and that the values are getting placed on a different sheet.

Comment: Are your variables declared propperly? Excel has a great way to check for this if you start your code with the line `option explicit`.

Comment: it is in the Sheet1 code module.  Its part of a bigger Sub and everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: Is there any screenupdating being set to false? If so you need to turn that back to true to see the actual changes. You could check in the immediate window what the value of your cells is, to see if it is a display issie, or if the value isnt set correctly

Comment: Luuklag, yes I used Option Explicit to start the Sheet1 Module

Comment: the code is full of similar statements - all of which work.  That is why this is so unusual.  I just added  this loop.  At first I thought it was because the loop wasn't working correctly, but all of the values are correct when I step through it.  It shows me that Sheet1.Range("H" & rw).Value is 800 and that FreightTotal is 900, but will not change the cell.

Comment: Are we sure that Sheet1 is the same sheet as Worksheets("Sheet1")? Codenames and sheet names can get out of step

Comment: Sheet1 is the correct reference.   Is there a way to attach the entire code?

Comment: OK, problem solved!  I shut down excel and restarted my computer.  Now everything works.  I would love to know what caused that.  Thanks for the comments, guys!